# It is possible to record a data that have a straight row in mysql based on date or sequence?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to get the data that have a straight Sell more than 3 times, it is possible in mysql? If not, how to get it right? I'm need it on mysql or php.

```
my database:-
+----------+---------------------+--------+
| Username | Date                | Action |
+----------+---------------------+--------+
| Adam     | 2014-08-20 22:30:20 | Sell   |
| Adam     | 2014-08-20 22:30:20 | Sell   |
| Adam     | 2014-08-20 22:30:20 | Sell   |
| Adam     | 2014-08-20 22:30:20 | Buy    |
| Adam     | 2014-08-20 22:30:20 | Buy    |
| Adam     | 2014-08-20 22:30:20 | Sell   |
| Adam     | 2014-08-20 22:30:20 | Sell   |
| Adam     | 2014-08-20 22:30:20 | Sell   |
| Adam     | 2014-08-20 22:30:20 | Sell   |
| Nick     | 2014-08-20 22:30:20 | Sell   |
| Nick     | 2014-08-20 22:30:20 | Sell   |
| Nick     | 2014-08-20 22:30:20 | Sell   |
| Nick     | 2014-08-20 22:30:20 | Sell   |
| Nick     | 2014-08-20 22:30:20 | Buy    |
+----------+---------------------+--------+
```

From the table above, I need to list out all data that have a straight sell more then 3 times.

```
RESULT
+----------+---------------------+--------+-------------+
| Username | Date                | Action | Straight 3+ |
+----------+---------------------+--------+-------------+
| Adam     | 2014-08-20 22:30:20 | Sell   |     3       |
| Adam     | 2014-08-20 22:30:20 | Sell   |     4       |
| Nick     | 2014-08-20 22:30:20 | Sell   |     4       |
+----------+---------------------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: Yes, you can use MySQL's aggregate [`COUNT()`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-count/) function, which is one way.

Comment: Read on MySQL GROUP BY and HAVING. I'm not interested in helping you as it seems to me you haven't tried! Post your query code and more people will be interested to help.

Comment: @Ananth: `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` by themselves do not help, as `GROUP BY` is position-agnostic; you'd need a cumulative/consecutive grouping, which is not something you can do in SQL without resorting to variables, as John Ruddell did. It is not a very simple solution unless you already know the trick. I am all for closing stupid no-effort questions with simple answers, but this does not qualify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT username, date, action, num_times as 'Straight 3+'
FROM
(   SELECT *,
        SUM(case action WHEN 'Sell' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_times,
        if(@a = action, @b, @b:= @b + 1) as counting_col,
        @a := action
    FROM your_table
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @a := '', @b := 1) t
    GROUP BY username, counting_col
    HAVING num_times > 0
) t1
```

working [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af2c95/2)

Comment: Thank very much @JohnRuddel. Very2 helpfull.